# ``Error when covert pb to tflite SSD_MobileNet_V2 - Windows 10

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, mobilenet

I am newbie to Tensorflow
I'm trying to convert `pb` to `tflite` but when I use this command

```
tflite_convert --graph_def_file=graph\tflite_graph.pb --output_file=output.tflite \
--input_shapes=1,300,300,3 --input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor \
--output_arrays='TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1', \
'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3' \
--inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 --mean_values=128 --std_dev_values=128 \
--change_concat_input_ranges=false --allow_custom_ops
```

I get this error

```
> Check failed: GetOpWithOutput(model, output_array) Specified output array "'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess'" is not produced by any op in this graph. Is it a typo? This should not happen. If you trigger this error please send a bug report (with code to reproduce this error), to the TensorFlow Lite team.
```

Please help me.

Comment: can you add your code or upload into google colab so anyone could reproduce this with minimal effort?

Comment: @eugen I use this repo to convert to tflite and it does not works [EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10)

Comment: I just change Faster_RCNN to SSD_Mobilenet_v2, but it does not matters because tflite_convert still does not works in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

First, you convert using export_tflite_ssd_graph.py. Pay attention to max_detections to get good performance on mobile.

```py
python export_tflite_ssd_graph.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path training_ssd_v2_config --trained_checkpoint_prefix ../output/model.ckpt-124960 --output_directory ../output/frozen_tflite/frozen_inference_graph.pb -add_postprocessing_op True --max_detections 10
```

Second, use tflite_convert with tensorflow (or tensorflow-gpu) version 1.11:

```py
tflite_convert --output_file=./tflite/detect.tflite
--graph_def_file=/home/nguyen/ssd/Foods/dataset/OD_food_non_food/ssd_model/output/frozen_tflite/frozen_inference_graph.pb/tflite_graph.pb
--input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor
--output_arrays='TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3'
--input_shape=1,300,300,3
--allow_custom_ops
```

Also have a look at these links

- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22564
- https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py